# IBM MQ Send and Receive Message

Tags: java, jms, message-queue, ibm-mq

I have following code to send request and receive response from IBM MQ. I know the code is IBM Implementation specific, but I am trying to get some result. Later I will do changes in the code to make it more generic.

```
       MQQueueConnectionFactory cf = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
       cf.setHostName("xx.xxx.xx.xxx");
       cf.setPort(xxxx);


       cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);

       cf.setQueueManager("Q_MANAGER");
       cf.setChannel("CHANNEL");


       MQQueueConnection connection = (MQQueueConnection) cf.createQueueConnection();

       MQQueueSession session = (MQQueueSession) connection.createQueueSession(true, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
       MQQueue queue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///REQ_Q");
       MQQueue respQueue = (MQQueue) session.createQueue("queue:///RESP_Q");

       MQQueueSender sender =  (MQQueueSender) session.createSender(queue);

       // set message properties
       TextMessage message = (TextMessage) session.createTextMessage("message to send");    
       message.setJMSReplyTo(respQueue);

       // Start the connection
       connection.start();
       sender.send(message);
       session.commit();

       String selecter = "JMSCorrelationID = '"+message.getJMSCorrelationID()+"'";
       MQQueueReceiver receiver = (MQQueueReceiver)session.createReceiver(respQueue, selecter);

       Message messageText;
      messageText = receiver.receive(5000);
```

The message is sent successfully. But I get null as the response, where actually there should be some response. What am I missing?

Comment: What steps have you taken to confirm there is a message on the response queue and that it is available to be consumed? 

You've started the connection which is the usual thing that is forgotten.!  Is the response being put under a transaction that is not comitted?

Answer (score 2):

How do you know that the other application sent you a response?  Did you check the response queue?

```
String selecter = "JMSCorrelationID = '"+message.getJMSCorrelationID()+"'";
```

What in the world is that?  Did the other application team tell you that the response message's CorrelID would have the original message's MessageID?  If so, you are using the wrong value.

Hence, you need to be using the MessageID value from the message you sent the other application. i.e.

```
String selecter = "JMSCorrelationID = '"+message.getJMSMessageID()+"'";
```